# Calculation in model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm builing a weight loss app. For this in my app each user `has_one :profile` and `has_many :weights`. Each profile `belongs_to :pal`. For my app to work I need a value called SMR which basically is a formula that takes as variables the user's size, age and gender (all from profiles table), the user's current weight (from weights table) as well as a float number from pal table.

I am able to calculate SMR in `profiles_controller.rb` show action and show it in the profiles show.html.erb.

I have two questions now:

1. Is it correct to do this calculation in the `profiles_controller.rb` show action or should I do it in the `profile.rb` model? If I should do it in the model: how can I do it (how should the code look like)?
2. I will need the SMR value later on in my app as a variable for other calculations as well. How can I achieve this (if it is calculated in the profile controller/model but needed somewhere else later on)?

I'm fairly new to the Rails world so maybe my questions are really noob questions.

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pal
  belongs_to :goal


  def age
    if birthdate != nil
      now = Time.now.utc.to_date
      now.year - birthdate.year - (birthdate.to_date.change(:year => now.year) > now ? 1 : 0)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

**weight.rb**

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**pal.rb**

```
class Pal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
end
```

**profiles_controller.rb (show action only)**

```
  def show
    @pal = @profile.pal
    @goal = @profile.goal
    @current_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order(:day).last

    if @profile.gender == 0
      @smr = (10*@current_weight.kilograms+6.25*@profile.size-5*@profile.age+5)*@pal.value
    elsif @profile.gender == 1
      @smr = (10*@current_weight.kilograms+6.25*@profile.size-5*@profile.age-161)*@pal.value
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your instincts are correct! No calculations in the model, you can do in the model that makes more sense, or create a Calculator class that receives `profile` and `current_weigh` and do the calculation. 

Regarding to 'I may need it later' I see that you have a Weight per day. You could store the calculated SMR for that weight and that day in the table itself and then just consult anywhere else. 

If no SMR is present, calculate and save it.

Comment: do calculatons in services

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should create a separate class or you can do on profile model as well

```
class SmrCalculator
  def initialize(profile, user)
     @profile = profile
     @user = user
  end

  def get_smr
    @pal = @profile.pal
    @goal = @profile.goal
    @current_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).last

    if @profile.gender == 0
      @smr = (10*@current_weight.kilograms+6.25*@profile.size-5*@profile.age+5)*@pal.value
    elsif @profile.gender == 1
      @smr = (10*@current_weight.kilograms+6.25*@profile.size-5*@profile.age-161)*@pal.value
    else
      nil
    end
  @smr
  end

end
```

And call this class on your controller show method like this:

```
@smr_calculator = SmrCalculator.new(@profile, current_user)
@smr = @smr_calculator.get_smr
```

And add this class as smr_calculator.rb in models folder

so anywhere in the app you need @smr you can call this class with profile and current user

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `services` directory inside `app` folder.And inside that you can create your class as `CalculatorService`.

Example:

```
class CalculatorService
  def initialize(profile, user)
     @profile = profile
     @user = user
  end

  def smr_value
    @pal = @profile.pal
    @goal = @profile.goal
    @current_weight = Weight.users_weight(@user.id)

    @smr = if @profile.gender == 0
      (10*@current_weight.kilograms + 6.25*@profile.size-5*@profile.age+5)*@pal.value
    elsif @profile.gender == 1
      (10*@current_weight.kilograms + 6.25*@profile.size-5*@profile.age-161)*@pal.value
    else
      nil
    end
    @smr
  end
end

 class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :users_weight, ->(user_id) { where(:user_id => user_id).order(:day).last}
end
```

And call this service in your controller like this:

```
@smr_calculator = CalculatorService.new(@profile, current_user)
@smr = @smr_calculator.smr_value
```